# Converts January 1, 0001 to the timestamp of the time library

Tags: python, time, format, valueerror, mktime

by python, i try to calculate the number of days from December 31, 9999 to January 1, 0001

```
import time

def days_diff(a, b):
    timestr_1 = "{}, {}, {}".format(a[0], a[1], a[2])
    time_1 = time.strptime(timestr_1, "%Y, %m, %d")
    timestr_2 = "{}, {}, {}".format(b[0], b[1], b[2])
    time_2 = time.strptime(timestr_2, "%Y, %m, %d")
    return int(abs(time.mktime(time_2) - time.mktime(time_1)) // 86400)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(days_diff((1, 1, 1), (9999, 12, 31)))
```

but

```
ValueError: time data '1, 1, 1' does not match 
format '%Y, %m, %d'
```

Answer (score 0):

`%Y`, `%m` & `%d` expect the numbers to be of lengths 4, 2, & 2 respectively. You can fix that issue with something like:

```py
import time

def padder(n, length):
    return str(n).zfill(length)

def days_diff(a, b):
    a = [padder(n,length) for n,length in zip(a,(4,2,2))]
    b = [padder(n,length) for n,length in zip(b,(4,2,2))]
    timestr_1 = "{}, {}, {}".format(a[0], a[1], a[2])
    time_1 = time.strptime(timestr_1, "%Y, %m, %d")
    timestr_2 = "{}, {}, {}".format(b[0], b[1], b[2])
    time_2 = time.strptime(timestr_2, "%Y, %m, %d")
    return int(abs(time.mktime(time_2) - time.mktime(time_1)) // 86400)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(days_diff((1, 1, 1), (9999, 12, 31)))
```

but that doesn't work (you get an `OverflowError`) because mktime doesn't support the date range.

Instead, try using `datetime.datetime`:

```py
import datetime as dt
def days_diff(a, b):
    time_1 = dt.datetime(*a)
    time_2 = dt.datetime(*b)
    diff = time_2-time_1
    return diff.days * 24 * 3600 + diff.seconds


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(days_diff((1, 1, 1), (9999, 12, 31)))
```

Comment: Accept my answer if it helped you please!